# How to Distribute Read-Only, Non-Paginated Documents?

Tags: publishing

Please, correct me if my understanding / assumptions are incorrect!

I believe that pdf, epub, mobi, etc. all must be paginated before publishing.  I would be happy to learn if I am wrong about that...

MS Word supposedly allows disabling pagination, but I am not sure if it only works in .doc or .docx specifically.  My quick googling did not come up with an answer RE .odf.

I am not really concerned if someone is hellbent on editing documents.  But, I am looking for something where accidental edits would be hard to make.

I believe MS Word will allow embedding a requirement for a password for editing the contents.  Again, though, not sure if that works for .doc and / or .docx.  My google-fu left me with the impression that .odf files do not have this option at all.

I am just looking for a document format that resizes itself for the device you are using like html in a web browser, i.e. read it on PC, read it on a Nook, Android Tablet, iPhone, etc., and has internal links from point a to point b inside the document.

I'd really prefer meta formatting as opposed to fixed, specific formatting. For example, a format that resizes / paginates on the fly.  If the document could use fonts selected by the user, that would be great.  Specifying where you require a monospace font would be good for things like code snippets, but letting the user / user's system decide which to use.

Pre-stylesheet HTML gets close, but even moderately complicated documents quickly become multi-file monsters. I am looking for a single file document or multi-file format that does not require the reader to be a computer power user.

On my Nook and Android phone, I find that ebooks with images would be improved if I could tap on the image and see it full screen.  Not holding my breath for that, but I mention it as another ideal document / reader detail.

I understand there may not be exacly such a beast.  Which tools do you recommend that get me close, if you don't know of one that does all of what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Most document types do not require pages.  Pages are set up by the author of the document, or by the software reading the document.

Take ereaders for example.  With epub, mobi, etc, pages are fluid.  When you resize the font or margins, the content of the page changes based on the user's preferences.  Many ereaders can give the user to read a PDF in its created form, which usually ends up scaling the document, making it hard to read.  However, many offer a way to reflow the content into a more readable format, which can look a little... funky sometimes.

Comment: I tried converting pdf to other formats using calibre.  The inconsistency of the results is part of what led me to my question.  I did not realize that epub or mobi did not require pagination.  I will do some googling / wiki-ing on creating those.

Comment: It has been a while since I visited this question.  Unless you know a trick I do not, epub / mobi cannot create scrollbars for tables that extend beyond the screen width.  Is that info, outdated?